# Suppress Powershell Errors while adding to $Error Variable

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exchange-server

I have a block of code executing that has been set up with a simple If/Else block to catch errors. I would normally use Try/Catch but the Exchange 2010 PS environment I'm working in doesn't allow me to use most of the Try/Catch features (and I can't update it or change it in any way because it's the customer's system and they're unwilling).

The issue is that while the code will function as expected when the Add-DistributionGroupMember cmdlet is set with -ErrorAction "Stop", it will output the error to the host each time, which annoys the customer (and me) because it's effectively just red noise since all the possible errors are being handled via a detailed output file.

If I set the cmdlet to -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" the error text is suppressed, but the Error is not added to the $Error[0] spot as I expected. The same is true of -ErrorAction "Ignore". The code requires that the Error be added to the $Error variable each time there is an error.

Here is the code:

```
$ListMembershipsIn | % {

        $Alias = $_.Alias
        $Member = $_.Member

        Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Alias -Member $Member -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop


        if($Error[0] -match "The recipient"){
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Already a member"
            Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "$($Alias),$($Member),Group already contains Member"
        }
        elseif($Error[0] -match "couldn't be found"){
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "not found"
            Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "Group does not exist or cannot be found,$($Alias),N/A"
        }
        elseif($Error[0] -match "couldn't find"){
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "not found"
            Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "Member does not exist or cannot be found,$($Alias),$($Member)"
        }
        elseif($Error[0] -match "There are Multiple"){
            Add-Content -Path $OuputPath -Value "Member name matches too many recipient - Add Member Manually,$($Alias),$($Member)"
        }
        else{
            Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "Member Successfully Added to Group,$($Alias),$($Member)"
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Throw Flag here"
        }
    }
```

Comment: A product in 2010 might likely be using PowerShell 2.0. PowerShell 3.0 came in Server 2012. Think of all the security holes the customer is leaving themselves open to. https://biztechmagazine.com/article/2017/01/how-guard-against-threats-microsoft-powershell-exploits

Comment: Fortunately all this work is to move them into Exchange Online so they're getting rid of all these old servers. The risk is certainly not lost on me.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for recourse, you can utilize the `-ErrorVariable` common parameter, or a `Try/Catch` block to interact with the specific error.

---

## ErrorVariable

When interacting with `ErrorVariable`, you can prepend the name with a `+` to append additional errors to it just like the `$Error` automatic variable, e.g.: `-ErrorVariable '+MyError'`

```
$ListMembershipsIn | ForEach-Object {
    $Alias = $_.Alias
    $Member = $_.Member
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Alias -Member $Member -ErrorVariable 'MyError'

    ## No error = good, continue the next iteration of the loop
    If (-not $MyError)
    {
        Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "Member Successfully Added to Group,$Alias,$Member"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Throw Flag here"
        Continue
    }

    Switch -Regex ($MyError.Exception.Message)
    {
        'The recipient'
        {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Already a member"
            Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "$Alias,$Member,Group already contains Member"
        }
        "couldn't be found"
        {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "not found"
            Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "Group does not exist or cannot be found,$Alias,N/A"
        }
        "couldn't find"
        {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "not found"
            Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "Member does not exist or cannot be found,$Alias,$Member"
        }
        'There are Multiple'
        {
            Add-Content -Path $OuputPath -Value "Member name matches too many recipient - Add Member Manually,$Alias,$Member"
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Try/Catch

```
$ListMembershipsIn | ForEach-Object {
    $Alias = $_.Alias
    $Member = $_.Member

    Try
    {
        Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Alias -Member $Member -ErrorAction 'Stop'

        ## No error thrown = successful processing
        Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "Member Successfully Added to Group,$Alias,$Member"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Throw Flag here"
    }
    Catch
    {
        Switch -Regex ($_.Exception.Message)
        {
            'The recipient'
            {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Already a member"
                Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "$Alias,$Member,Group already contains Member"
            }
            "couldn't be found"
            {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "not found"
                Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "Group does not exist or cannot be found,$Alias,N/A"
            }
            "couldn't find"
            {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "not found"
                Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "Member does not exist or cannot be found,$Alias,$Member"
            }
            'There are Multiple'
            {
                Add-Content -Path $OuputPath -Value "Member name matches too many recipient - Add Member Manually,$Alias,$Member"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a helpful demonstration of other ways one could go about writing a similar block of code, but it doesn't solve my problem.

And I suspect the reason why has something to do with my powershell environment. When I try the +MyError code, I get an error:

`A variable that cannot be referenced in restricted language mode or a Data section is being referenced.`

And it stops execution after one loop, without making it to the Switch block. I'm beginning to suspect these Exchange cmdlets are a little buggy..

Comment: @CharlieKing Did you try the Try/Catch method?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Add-DistributionGroupMember command doesn't fill ErrorVariable when specified.
I found no way to avoid the unwanted output, so I handled the error with Tristan's trick rather than by exception handling (which is absolutely fine, but not fitting my own dev):

```
$Error.clear()
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $mySite.MailingList -Member $emailAddress
if ($Error.count -eq 0) {
    $script:logger["ldissue"] += "<li>Liste de diffusion $($mySite.MailingList) : La ressource <b>$($ADRecord.Name)</b> ($($ADRecord.SamAccountName) - $($BoondRecord.flags)) a été ajoutée à la liste</li>"
} else {
    $script:logger["ldissue"] += "<li>Liste de diffusion $($mySite.MailingList) : La ressource <b>$($ADRecord.Name)</b> ($($ADRecord.SamAccountName) - $($BoondRecord.flags)) n'a pas pu être ajoutée à la liste (<i>$($Error[0])</i>)</li>"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the "-ErrorAction Continue" this won't suppress the error but it will ensure the script continues and it places the error in the $Error variable.

You can also use the $Error.clear() command to remove any stored errors in the session.

Comment: `If I set the cmdlet to -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" the error text is suppressed, but the Error is not added to the $Error[0] spot as I expected. The same is true of -ErrorAction "Ignore".` - Copied literally from his question..

Comment: I'm Sorry, I read the title and realized the OP wants the error suppressed and the error captured. I was testing with the -Continue which captured the error in the $error variable. What version of Powershell is the environment?

Comment: No worries. Tristan your answer would have worked if I just wanted to ignore the error and check it later. Unfortunately the requirements here meant that I need to suppress all that ugly red error text.